# How do I make my keyboard media keys control only the active playing media, instead of the default one?

Tags: windows-10

About half a year ago, everything was perfectly fine, if I had a media player, like YouTube Music app playing in the background, I could use media keys on my keyboard, and control it(pause, skip, stop). And if I had paused the player, opened some YouTube video, then my media keys would control that video instead of my player.

But after upgrading to Windows 11, where my media keys controlled only the player, if I had both a player and a video open, which meant that I had to manually pause the video, or close the player.

I then downgraded back to Windows 10, and for some reason, that feature of media keys controlling only the active media, was gone, and it works exactly the same as in Windows 11.
I'm pretty sure that I wasn't messing around in any registries or any hotkey software which could enable such functionality. Any ideas on how to do this WITHOUT any hotkey software? Thanks.